# error while running my main.dart file on android studio

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, android-studio, gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.13:.
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

it is showing this while i am trying to make my login and sign up page after setting up the Firebase
on my flutter app

I tried updating the studio and plugins and even restarted the project in a new folder

Comment: can you provide pubspec.yaml file content?

Comment: name: track_expenses_app
description: A new Flutter project. publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core:
  firebase_auth:
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images

Comment: Check out my answer below. Please do not add codes in comments, edit your question to provide necessary details instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the build.gradle file add the following line of code or go to firebase to find the latest version.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    /// other dependencies
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Update build.gradle with bellow line.

> dependencies
> {
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1' }

Solution 2:

> Update project's google-services.json file with your own google-services.json file.

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error occurs if you have mismatched firebase dependencies. It seems you are not specifying the firebase core and auth version in your pubspec.yaml

```
 dependencies:
    firebase_core: ^2.14.0
    firebase_auth: ^4.6.3
```

Few points to consider:

- Verify Firebase dependencies
- Clean and rebuild your project
- Update google service plugin
- Rebuild your project